# Json.Net IsoDateTimeConverter is not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

I have a web application made in asp.net mvc 4

in Global.asax, i added added `IsoDateTimeConverter`

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(
        new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm" });
}
```

I have an ActionResult

```
public ActionResult GetDate()
{
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
    return Json(dateTime, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

However, this actionResult returns this:

```
"\/Date(1365060823129)\/"
```

What i am missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I believe you got a little bit confused by all the *"not precise"* naming which lot of people have been using lately. The `JsonFormatter` (and formatters in general) is used by *ASP.NET Web API*.

You are not using *ASP.NET Web API*, you are using *ASP.NET MVC 4* (those are completely separated technologies).

In *ASP.NET MVC 4* the serialization logic is still done inside the `JsonResult` with `JavaScriptSerializer`, formatters are not applied here.

If you want to use *Json.NET* (and its `IsoDateTimeConverter`) with *ASP.NET MVC 4* you still need to create your own `ActionResult` as described [here](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-and-json-net.aspx).