# Date Format In MVC 4 API Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am facing some issue while return `JSON` response from `MVC4 API controller`(with the use of Default serializer). I need to get data response like `'2013-11-21 08:50:31'`, but it return like `'2013-11-22T02:40:28.22499'`.

Is it possible to change date format before serializing?

Comment: are you getting response client side or server side?

Comment: Server side response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put this in your `Application_Start()`:

```
var dateTimeConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter 
{ 
    DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" 
};

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings
                   .Converters.Add(dateTimeConverter);
```

Then all dates will be output in the desired format. Found through [On the nightmare that is JSON Dates. Plus, JSON.NET and ASP.NET Web API](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx) and [Json.Net IsoDateTimeConverter is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805108/json-net-isodatetimeconverter-is-not-working).

Answer (score 0):

The answer by CodeCaster works great but be aware that with the format `hh:mm:ss` the time `15:10:10` will be shown as `03:10:10`.

To show it as `15:10:10` use this format string instead: `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`.